How to get an json error when a specific route does not have a record
I am trying to build an API for posting and inserting data. so I can post data to the post end point, get all the data from the database and get a specific data from a particular row using the id. I would like when I try to query an ID that does not exist to return a json like this
[
    {
        "error": "no record found in DB"
    }
]

Here is the code that I am working with
app.get('/users/:id',async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const id = req.params.id
        
        conn = await pool.getConnection()
        const result = await conn.query("select * from info where id=?",id)
        if(!result){
            res.json({
                "error":"no such record in database"
            })
        }else{
            res.send(result)
        }
        
    } catch (error) {
        res.send(error)
    }
})

I tried using an if statement inside the block hoping that it would execute if query returned nothing, instead it returns an empty json

not related, but i would use const result = await pool.query("select * from info where id=?",id), because, you never give back the connection to pool, you'll face pool exhaustion at some point

In this scenario, await connection.query() won't return anything that could be considered "falsy"; as such your logic will never enter your logic branch gated with the simplistic if(!result) expression.
Instead, you should expect a successful query (one that may return 0 or more rows, but was otherwise successfully executed) to return an Array result-set. Test the length of the returned result set instead:
if (result.length === 0) { // ...


Tangential, but you should also consider returning 404 Not Found in this particular instance to indicate an error condition to your API's consumers.
